# How can i add merge icon(right shift) in all conflict text line in Angular Monaco Diff Editor

Tags: angular14, ngx-monaco-editor

I am implementing the Angular Monaco diff editor where left and right side text are showing correct diff and also highlight correctly but text merge from let to right side only visible on empty text area where my requirement is to show this icon in all the text conflict line.[image]

I am using the angular 14 with [ngx-monaco-editor-v2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-monaco-editor-v2) use the sample code. saw different options too but did not found any solution yet.